# How can I alter the sort order of a field within Crystal Reports?

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, report

I have built a report in Crystal which lists prices by location by product.  The products are grouped into categories.  The query is based in Microsoft SQL Server.  The report users want the products in a customized order, which I can build into the query but is not reflected within the database/formula fields in Crystal.  What I want is [Can't post images due to being new] ...

Grouped by Unit of Measurement, grouped by Product Type, listed by Product, locations across the top, prices listed for each product by location... but I need the products in order: 8, 3, 5, 9, etc.

How do I get it to sort by this custom order?  In query form, I just hard-coded an order to the products (temporarily, this will only be 20 items or so), but that order doesn't carry over into the report because I can't sort the field by another field.

The query that follows does not have the sorting.  I sorted it by using `CASE WHEN ProductID = X THEN Y` and added an `ORDER BY` at the end.  This worked within the SQL server but not on Crystal.

```
DECLARE @Customer AS nvarchar(10)
SET @Customer ='99999'       'This is changed to {Customer} form on Crystal.

SELECT CustData.Name + ' (' + CustData.CustomerID + ')' AS Customer
,CASE WHEN LocatInv.LocReg1 = '' THEN 101 ELSE 0 END AS LocReg
,ISNULL(Syc.Description,'') Type
,LocatInv.Description + ' (' + RIGHT(LocatInv.LocationID, 2) + ')'
 AS Location
,ProductF.Description + ' (' + ProductF.ProductID + ')' AS Product
,PricingI.Price1 AS Price, ProductF.Unit

FROM LocatInv WITH (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN LocatProd ON LocatInv.LocationID = LocatProd.LocationID
INNER JOIN ProductF ON ProductF.ProductID = LocatProd.ProductID
INNER JOIN PricingI ON PricingI.LocationID = LocatProd.LocationID
 AND PricingI.ProductID = LocatProd.ProductID
INNER JOIN CustData ON CustData.PriceListID = PricingI.PriceListID
LEFT JOIN (select DISTINCT Syclass.ItemID, Syclass.Description
 FROM Syclass WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Syclass.ClassID='CLASSPR3') Syc
ON ProductF.ProductClass3 = Syc.ItemID
WHERE LocatProd.Active = 'A' AND CustData.CustomerID=@Customer
 AND ProductF.UserField1 = 'A'
```

Comment: Show us the query so we can help.

Comment: Have you created grouping levels in the crystal report? Do you want to sort before or after the groupings are sorted?

Comment: Yes.  I created a group 2 header/footer which prints at the top and bottom of the report and then a group 3 header based on type.  Group 1 is suppressed.  The cross tab then layers row 1 and 2 against column 1 (1 is unit, 2 is product, column is location).  I want to sort the product (currently row 2) by this customized order.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a picture would help to answer..but will try to answer

If you have grouped according to product then you go to the change group and in that go to tab custom... There you mention the order how you want to display